# Difficult Equation Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I'm having a trouble with equation alignment. I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  a & = b\\
    & = c
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  \sqrt{a v} & = \frac{c d}{e f}\\
             & = f
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  g & = h+l+k+fg\\
    & = i
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

the problem is that *I want to have the equal sign of the three equation env. aligned together* AND *the numbering of equations precisely like this* (i.e. the number between first and second line of each aligned block). Moreover a page brake occur between before the last equation env. How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` inside `align` (but only one alignment point is allowed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a         & = b\\
          & = c
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
\sqrt{av} & = \frac{c d}{e f}\\
          & = f
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}
g         & = h+l+k+fg\\
          & = i
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When the document is in its final form and you need to break such a display, add `\displaybreak` before the `\\` item after which you need the page break.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `align` and `\mathllap` might do the trick. `\allowdisplaybreaks` enables page breaking between lines in an `align` (and `gather`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 &\begin{aligned}
   \mathllap{a} & = b\\
    & = c
 \end{aligned} \\
 &\begin{aligned}
  \mathllap{\sqrt{av}} & = \frac{c d}{e f}\\
             & = f
 \end{aligned} \\
 &\begin{aligned}
  \mathllap{g} & = h+l+k+fg\\
    & = i
 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```